# Как сделать присвоение названию переменной значение переменной?

Tags: javascript

Как следующий код переписать в цикл

```
p1=document.getElementById('p1').innerHTM
p2=document.getElementById('p2').innerHTML
p3=document.getElementById('p3').innerHTML
p4=document.getElementById('p4').innerHTML
p5=document.getElementById('p5').innerHTML
p6=document.getElementById('p6').innerHTML
p7=document.getElementById('p7').innerHTML
p8=document.getElementById('p8').innerHTML
p9=document.getElementById('p9').innerHTML
```

Ожидаю чего-то подобного:

```
for (i=1;i<10;i++){
    p+i=document.getElementById('p'+i).innerHTML
}

function setV(id){ 
    //функция получает подобные значения id="p1"
    id=document.getElementById(id)
    //нужно что-бы название переменной соответствовало id (как пример p1)
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам столько переменных-то? Чем массивы не угодили?

Comment: Так надо. вообще крестики нолики делал.
http://buh-edu.zzz.com.ua/hub/xo/

Comment: Для крестиков-ноликов вполне сгодится массив из девяти элементов (или матрица 3x3 - тогда вообще можно запилить крестики-нолики произвольного размера, хоть прямоугольные)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доступ к свойствам объекта представляют точечная и скобочная записи. Выглядит это вот так:

```
object.property
object["property"]
```

Такое обращение к переменным заложено ещё в изначальном определении JavaScript и выполнено в JavaScript 1.0.

Если ваша переменная лежит в [глобальной области видимости](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx), то можно использовать скобочную запись `window["property"]`.

Так мы можем записать для глобальной области видимости `window["p1"] = "Привет"` и позднее обращение `console.log(p1)` выведет нам:

> Привет

Поэтому вашу задачу можно решить так:

```js
for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++)
 window['p'+i] = document.getElementById('p'+i).innerHTML;

console.log(p5);
```

```html
<p id="p1">Данные из p1</p>
<p id="p2">Данные из p2</p>
<p id="p3">Данные из p3</p>
<p id="p4">Данные из p4</p>
<p id="p5">Данные из p5</p>
<p id="p6">Данные из p6</p>
<p id="p7">Данные из p7</p>
<p id="p8">Данные из p8</p>
<p id="p9">Данные из p9</p>
```

Подробнее об обращении к переменным, а точнее к свойствам объекта можно почитать [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).